# Is there an efficient way to have a button automatically copy text to your clipboard? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I've read this entire post on how to copy text to a clipboard, and none of it seems to match what I'm looking for. [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-)

The program has several fields that are going to have text entered into them, that will then be copied and dropped into several other applications. I found a quick way to do this in IE, but it won't work in any other browser. Here's the HTML.

```
<SPAN ID="copytext" STYLE="height:150;width:162;background-color:pink">
This text will be copied onto the clipboard when you click the button below. Try it!
</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;">
</TEXTAREA>
<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">Copy to Clipboard</BUTTON>
```

And then here's the JavaScript.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function ClipBoard() 
{
holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}

</SCRIPT>
```

The program can't have something like Zero Clipboard or Clippy, because it still needs to work if I put it on a different computer without those libraries. The best shot I've had was one on the link posted at the top of this article. It uses jQuery.

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

try {
  var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
  var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
  console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Oops, unable to copy');}});
```

So that works great for one field, but everything I've ever learned about programming tells me not to repeat myself over and over again. ESPECIALLY if I'm only changing one thing every time I repeat it. Is there a better way to do this? Or is jQuery and repetition my only option at this point?

Comment: If you don't mind sacrificing Safari browsers then just use https://clipboardjs.com/ . You can just copy paste the raw code in your existing JavaScript block to if you don't want external files.

Comment: "The program can't have something like Zero Clipboard or Clippy, because it still needs to work if I put it on a different computer without those libraries. "  bundle the library with your program?

Comment: I'm still super new to creating my own projects... I didn't know you could bundle libraries to your programs... Let me research that... That may be my best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this recently

```
 document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("hexVal"));
});

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
      // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
          succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}


<input type="text" id="hexVal" />
<span id="copyButton">Copy</span>
```